# Execute export command in windows

Tags: php, homestead

Hello I am trying to execute this command:

> export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"

in windows.

Comment: i am working on this excersice https://laravel-news.com/your-first-laravel-application

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. please read guidelines on posting new questions. Also describe what have you tried so far and add minimum working example wherever required.

Comment: actually i'm working on an excersice whic is given in this link https://laravel-news.com/your-first-laravel-application  

this was the instruction given in the tutorial : 

You need to make sure that the global Composer bin is in your path. You can do so by adding the following to your PATH in your ~/.bash_profile or ~/.zshrc if you are using Z shell: 

 export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH" in windows.

but i did not understand how to do this step i need some help

Answer (score 0):

Please, check these [notes](https://laravel-news.com/your-first-laravel-application)

> Note: For the local PHP environment I am using a Mac and Valet because it automatically sets up everything. If you are on Windows, you should consider **Homestead** or some flavor of a virtual machine.

Comment: we are using homestead on windows

Comment: @greeshma y, the command is for linux, macOS..Although, you set `path` manually, it would be better to look for other windows tutorial.